# Is $g \circ f$ map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$? yes/no

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the  following statement is true/false ?

let $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ and $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be linear  transformation

then $gf :\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$  is a linear transformation

My attempt : I think this statement is **false**  because here codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ so it should be $gf :\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$  is a linear transformation

Comment: In the title it should be both $\mathbb R^3$ , right ?

Comment: @Physor no that title show that  whether my  attempt  is true/false

Comment: gf means $g \circ f$ right?

Comment: yes. same meaning @Shanna

Comment: $g \circ f: \mathbb{R}^3 \overset{f}{\to} \mathbb{R}^2 \overset{g}{\to} \mathbb{R}^3$, isn't it?

Comment: okss   got  it now @Shanna thanks for this logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension of the image of $f$, which is a subspace in $\mathbb R^2$, is at most $2$, the same is also true for $g$, where image of the latter is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, and that is because the *domain* is 2-dimensional.

The linearity of $g \circ f$
$$
f(au+bv) = af(u) + bf(v) \in \mathbb R^2
$$
$$
(g\circ f)(au+bv) =
g(f(au+bv)) = g(af(u) + bf(v))\\ = ag(f(u))+bg(f(v)) = a\ (g\circ f)u + b\ (g\circ f)v \in \mathbb R^3
$$

Comment: @ancientmathematician I think it is now correct

Comment: OK, but as stated the question is about codomains, and is answered in @Shanna's comment

Comment: should I remove the answer ?

Comment: @Physor    It's okay no need to remove